# Stop a function in the form with 'Cancel" button in the messagBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I put s messageBox in my Button Event that when user click on the button that MessageBox will show to user and it has Okay and Cancel Buttons in the MessageBox.
Now when user click on Okay and Cancel button it will done a same function.
But i wanna when user click on the cancel Button Stop that function and back to the form.
Just imagine when user click on the Okay button it will open a new WebBrowser which direct to DropBox Site for download something.
But when user click on the cancel button it will do same thing. But i don't want.
I just searched and find a code which include this but when i put in my program nothing happened and again cancel button will open a new WebBrowser.
You can see my code in the Code sample below :

```
        private void btnWCS2016_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr =  MessageBox.Show("Hint :\nRaR password : vortex\n\n Winner : Polt (Terran)\n\nDownload require : 57.166 MB","User advice",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=WCS-+Winter+2016.rar");
        if(dr==DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: **1-** Show dialog  **2-** Check if dialog result is `DialogResult.OK` then start process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start the process before checking the returned value from the message box. 
Either move the process start after the condition, like this:

```
private void btnWCS2016_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr =  MessageBox.Show("Hint :\nRaR password : vortex\n\n Winner : Polt (Terran)\n\nDownload require : 57.166 MB","User advice",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if(dr==DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        return;
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=WCS-+Winter+2016.rar");
}
```

or change the condition and put it inside, like this:

```
private void btnWCS2016_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr =  MessageBox.Show("Hint :\nRaR password : vortex\n\n Winner : Polt (Terran)\n\nDownload require : 57.166 MB","User advice",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if(dr==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=WCS-+Winter+2016.rar");

    }
}
```

Personally I prefer the second way in this case, since it's only one row code. if it was a massive code block i would prefer the first way.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `Kill()` method to stop the process.

```
private void btnWCS2016_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DialogResult dr =  MessageBox.Show("Hint :\nRaR password : vortex\n\n Winner : Polt (Terran)\n\nDownload require : 57.166 MB","User advice",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

       if(dr==DialogResult.Cancel)
       {
           return; 
       }

      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=WCS-+Winter+2016.rar");


    }
```

Comment: No point of starting a process and then killing it when you can avoid starting it in the first place....

Comment: Your edit is better, but there is no point in the two conditions here- The `DialogResult` can only be either `OK` or `Cancel`, and You already exit the method if the first condition evaluates to `true`.